# PHP concatenation for wordpress homepage img src

Tags: php, concatenation

I've tried my best to looking for other questions similar to mine, but couldn't find any.

I have a php code to show for my homepage only but am having a hard time concatenating this correctly so that the img src php can work properly inside the php tags. I'm still new to php and this is confusing me a bit. Could anyone show me the correct way?

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    echo '
    <div id="demo">
    <img alt="background" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/img1.png"/>
    <div id="block" ></div>
    <img alt="logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/img2.png"/>
    </div>'; }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PHP tags inside anymore since its already inside your PHP script. Just concatenate that function you're calling.

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    echo '
        <div id="demo">
            <img alt="background" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/img1.png"/>
        <div id="block" ></div>
        <img alt="logo" src="' .get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/img2.png"/>
        </div>
    '; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use separate tags than try like this.

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <div id="demo">
    <img alt="background" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/img1.png"/>
    <div id="block" ></div>
    <img alt="logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/img2.png"/>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a php tag anymore.

```
<?php 
    if (is_front_page()){
        echo "<div id='demo'> <img alt='background' src='".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/img1.png'/> <div id='block' ></div> <img alt='logo' src='".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/img2.png'/> </div>"; 
    } 

?>
```